# Accessing a perl array that's name is stored in a string

Tags: perl

If I have the name of an array stored in a variable, i.e.

```
$var = "@array"
```

Is there any way for me to access

```
$array[0]
```

from only this information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to do that. Please read [this](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html), as well as the linked parts 2 and 3. Then forget about your question and use a hash.

Comment: If you explain in a bit more words why you are trying to do this we might be able to help you do it in a different way. Please [edit] your question and include more of your code. Also explain why you have a variable that contains a variable name. What problem are you trying to solve with that? You're likely just missing the understanding of one of the basic concepts of programming. It will be like an epiphany once you get it, followed by a facepalm. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign an array to a var like that, it'll auto-join it using `$"`.

So you can split based on `$"` and reverse it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw ( fish carrot banana );
my $var = "@array";
print +(split (/\Q$"\E/, $var))[0],"\n";
```

But this is a bad idea - it'll trip up on a bunch of things, not least 'does my array contain spaces in the elements' - there's no good exhaustive solution to this that isn't serialisation via something like `JSON` or `YAML`.

Having reread your question, it seems you're trying to do a symbolic reference, rather than what I thought.

That's a terrible idea, and you should not do it.

Please see: [Why it's a bad idea to use a variable as a variable name](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

The short of it is - it's an extremely bad practice, that may be technically possible in certain situations, but extremely few of those apply to real world coding.

> The real root of the problem code is: It's fragile. You're mingling unlike things when you do this. And if two of those unlike things happen to have the same name, they'll collide and you'll get the wrong answer. So you end up having a whole long list of names which you have to be careful not to reuse, and if you screw up, you get a very bizarre error. This is precisely the problem that namespaces were invented to solve, and that's just what a hash is: A portable namespace.

Just use a hash, and use hash keys as your symbolic reference.

Comment: I didn't even think about this. You're right of course. But then the question text says the name is in the array, so OP is contradicting themselves. If it's `$var = '@array'` they have the name of the variable, and my comment applies. If they have `$var = "@array"` they have something else entirely, and your answer applies.

Comment: Just cite question: "I have the name of an array stored in a variable", so solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445799/accessing-a-perl-array-thats-name-is-stored-in-a-string/46446953#46446953

Comment: I misread it. But the that's not the answer either. The answer is 'don't do it'.

Comment: Question is "Is there any way for me to access $array[0] from only this information?" - Answer is "how to do it". "Don't do it" - just recommendation.

Comment: "How do I commit suicide with a shotgun?" "Don't". The problem here is an XY problem - the _actual problem_ will be something different.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use PadWalker qw/peek_my/;

my @array = (1, 2, 3);

my $var = '@array';

my $lexical = peek_my(0);

print $lexical->{$var}->[0];
```

Here $lexical->{$var} references to your's @array.

peek_my's argument is level of scope (see [PadWalker](http://search.cpan.org/~robin/PadWalker-2.2/PadWalker.pm) for details).

Comment: @charlie-bradford are answers helped you? please vote for right one :)